# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponseCode' of undefined doGet_Appraisal throws error but before it was executed properly how to resolve

Tags: google-apps-script

```
It was actually a Google Sheets project, so I'm learning on the fly as best as I can, but I can't even format this code below correctly - ugh!)  
The error I am receiving is this:

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponseCode' of undefined
    doGet_Appraisal @ Appraisal_Email.gs:64

And the code is below:
```

//1. Performing to generate the Payslip getting sheet contents

```
  function doGet_Appraisal(range,shTabName) {
  var blob,exportUrl,name,options,response,sheetTabId,ss,ssID,url_base,email,subject;
  var folderId ="1o9WImzeKdzsek7DfZWD_qzFsI9yLoplz";
  var milliseconds = 2000;
  range = range ? range : "B1:R44";
  
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet_ID");
  shTabName = "Appraisal Payslip Template";  
  ssID = ss.getId();
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(shTabName);  
  const body = "Dear Employee" + "\n\n" + "<p>" + "<b> Payslip for the month of January is Available </b>" + "</p>"; 
  var htmlText = body.replace(/\n/g,'\n<br>');

  var bioCode = sh.getRange('F12');
  const values = [...new Set(bioCode.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat())];  
  var first = values[0];               
  var number = values.length - 1;       
  bioCode.setValue(first);
```

//2. Looping the Emp_ID till null

```
  for(i = 0;i < number;i++) 
  { 
  if (sh.getRange('F12').getValue().length > 0) { 
  var person = sh.getRange('F12').getValue();
  sheetTabId = sh.getSheetId();
```

//3. Getting the Corresponfing EMail based on Emp_ID

```
  email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Appraisal Payslip Template').getRange('N12').getValue().toString(); 
  Utilities.sleep(milliseconds);
  url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  name = sh.getRange("S1").getValue();
  name = name + ""
  subject = `${name}`; 
  Logger.log('email: ' + email)
  Logger.log('body: ' + body)
```

//4. Exporting the sheet as PDF (contents)

```
  exportUrl = url_base + 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +

    '&gid=' + sheetTabId + '&id=' + ssID +
    '&range=' + range + 
    '&size=A4' +    
    '&portrait=true' +   
    '&fitw=true' +      
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true' + 
    '&gridlines=false' + 
    '&fzr=false';
```

//5. Authorizing email setup OAuthToken

```
  options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }
```

//6. Getting the sheet url and export as PDF

```
  options.muteHttpExceptions = true;
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, options);
  //var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, options).getBlob();

  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode())

  const nextValue = values[values.indexOf(bioCode.getValue()) + 1] || values[0];
  bioCode.setValue(nextValue);
  }
  else {const nextValue = values[values.indexOf(bioCode.getValue()) + 1] || 
  values[0];
  bioCode.setValue(nextValue);
  }
```

//7. If response code is not 200 return error exporting PDF

```
  if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    console.log("Error exporting Sheet to PDF!  Response Code: " + response.getResponseCode());
    return;
  }
  blob = response.getBlob();
  blob.setName(name + '.pdf')
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, htmlText, 
  {
    htmlBody: htmlText,
    attachments: [{
      fileName: `${name}` + ".pdf",
      //content: response2.getBytes(),
      mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
  });


   //pdfFile = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob);

 }
}



This was worked recently but now throws error
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponseCode' of undefined
doGet_Appraisal @ Appraisal_Email.gs:64

Comment: I found the bug: there was an issue of getting the array of values
'const values = [...new Set(bioCode.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat())]; '
I declared values in integers, whereas the expected array values are in string.

Comment: Hi, In the future, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about how to produce a reproducible minimal example to allow people to try your code and help you better.